# Defer parsing of JavaScript

Tags: plugins, javascript

When I test my page speed for the site (https://sunshineecocleaningservices.com.au/) it gives the score of 0 for defer parsing of JavaScript "3.6MiB of JavaScript is parsed during initial page load. Defer parsing JavaScript to reduce blocking of page rendering."
Although JS minification is there. How to resolve this? Is there any plugin or something.

Comment: what kind of page speed test you use for this result? You may need to provide that so that other could produce same result in order to give you a hand.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be careful with PageSpeed and GTMetrix and other such tools because the provide results without context.  They have pre-set rules like 'scripts should be deferred and/or loaded at the end of the page above the closing `</body>` tag.  But some scripts can't be deferred if you want them to provide the functionality they were intended to provide and some have to load in the header (Facebook's scripts do this, LinkedIn too).  So they're great tools to test and check and get a sense of where you *could* make improvements, but that doesn't mean they're always 100% correct in what they're telling you to do.

That said, here's what I use on sites to add a defer tag to scripts that are being loaded.

```
function addaprefix_defer_js( $url ) {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) return $url;
    if ( FALSE === strpos( $url, '.js' ) ) return $url;
    //you'll want to add a list of scripts here that you do NOT want to defer, jquery.js is definately one of them
    if ( strpos( $url, 'jquery.js' ) ) return $url; 
    return str_replace( ' src', ' defer src', $url );
}
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'addaprefix_defer_js', 10 );
```

Where I have `addaprefix_` change that to whatever you want/need the prefix of your functions to be.